# Insert query with select query from 2 tables which don't have common column to join

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

This might be simple question but i do not know how to write sql query for that.

I have below scenario:

Table 1:

```
id    name
1     aaaa
2     bbbb
3     cccc
4     dddd
```

Table 2:

```
id    name
1     xxxx
2     yyyy
```

Output Table - Mapping table between Table 1 and Table 2:

```
id     Table1_id     Table2_id
1         1             1
2         1             2
3         2             1
4         2             2
5         3             1
6         3             2
7         4             1
8         4             2
```

i want to write insert query for the above output table

SQL like below

```
insert into output_table(table1_id, table2_id)
select table1.table1_id, .... 
from table1 .... ?
```

Please note that there is no joining column between these two tables and for each id in table1 should map with both id's (1 and 2) should have an entry in output table.

Can someone help me to write this query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CROSS JOIN`. This will generate a cartesian product between both tables, which seems to be what you are looking for.

```
INSERT INTO output_table(table1_id, table2_id)
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN table2 t2
```

This can also be spelled as follows (using an implicit join):

```
INSERT INTO output_table(table1_id, table2_id)
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
```

Comment: Thank you @GMB for quick response. If i have where clause for table1 how should i apply this?

Comment: @user10566909: the WHERE clause goes at the end of the query, after the FROM clause (and after the JOIN).